# Can't boot into 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb, cd

My laptop is Benq with Windows XP. The CD-ROM is not working and my BIOS can't support booting from USB. What should I do?

I tried to mount the ISO file that I downloaded. It auto-runs and prompts me to either (1) reboot now, (2) reboot later, or (3) help to start up the live CD (it is mounted by daemon tools).

When I choose to reboot now (or reboot later and reboot it), it reboots and nothing happens and it boots Windows XP.

When I choose to help start up the live CD, it pops out an error `string index out of range` once it finished and it said to reboot PC, so I rebooted and there was no option to choose Ubuntu.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

cd not working and usb boot not supported, if winxp still boots, try the windows installer:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=wubi&release=&bits=

Comment: Tried. Installed something rebooted and still nothing happens.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Maybe it will let me to install if i install an older ubuntu version like 11.10 desktop i386. what do you think?